# How to display lookup value from related object and opportunity in the same page?

Tags: visualforce, button-overrides, page-override

I have an object that is related to an opportunity.

I want to override the new opportunity page, so when creating a new opportunity, a related record will also be created.

I am able to create the VF page for new oppty:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>

                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>

                        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.name}"/><r/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.CloseDate}"/><br/>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.accountid }"/><br/>                             
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.StageName  }"/><br/>                             
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Campaignid}"/><br/>                             

                </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The page looks like this:
[image]

But here I need that another fields will show:

```
Competitive.Product
```

Competitive.Product is a lookup field on the Competitive_Offer object.

This is Competitive_Offer record page:
[image]

I can add the following on the VF page:

```
<apex:inputText label="Competitive Product" id="Competitive_Product"/>
```

The page would than look like this:
[image]

But since it's a lookup field, how can I have it select from the appropriate records?

The competitive record will be created with the new Opportunity id that was just created.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You would have to using an extension which would have logic to save child object

Comment: Thank youI need to display the input fields. This is before the extension, which I know I need to use.